# The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'.  Try importing the library that defines 'instance', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'instance'.

I am trying to implement this sample code
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart 
But it is showing above mentioned error. 
How to fix it?

`firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3`
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

[image: fcm flutter]

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written? Specifically the imports and the error causing line ?

Comment: @MidhunMP updated with question

Comment: The instance property is available in the version 8 (which is in pre-release status). In 7 you have to use `FirebaseMessaging()` to create instance.

Answer (score 1):

The getter 'instance' is not available on `firebase_messaging: ^7.x.x` , you will need to upgrade to version 8

Comment: there is no version 8 in `firebase_messaging` ! You must have to use version 9.0 or above!